# Icon is a dark square in SFML

Tags: c++, icons, sfml

When I tried to load an icon from a file and display it, the icon of my window became a dark square. This is my code, if you spot a problem please reply, thanks.

```
sf::Image icon;
icon.loadFromFile("greenball.png"); 
window.setIcon(icon.getSize().x, icon.getSize().y, icon.getPixelsPtr());
```

Comment: Are you sure the icon variable is dropping out of scope and the image is being deallocated?

Answer (score 2):

Always check, if an I/O operation succeeded. There's nothing else to fail, it must be that you're giving it an invalid file path or the file doesn't exist.

[`sf::Image::loadFromFile`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php#a9e4f2aa8e36d0cabde5ed5a4ef80290b) returns `bool` indicating success, so use it.

Comment: It loaded, but it still displays a dark square

Comment: Strange. What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows Xp, it might be too old

Comment: SFML says xp is fully supported, though. Maybe try their forum for this sort of "bug question".